# Ao clicar em um botão o Teclado fecha utilizando Ionic

Tags: android, ios, apache-cordova, ionic

Alguem já passou por isso?, 
Eu gostaria que o teclado continuasse aberto, tipo WhatsApp, messenger, que vc envia a mensagem e o teclado continua aberto.

Estou utilizando Ionic e desenvolvendo para android 6.0 (marshmallow)

Answer (score 1):

Faltam informações para uma resposta mais exata, comece me dizendo se vc esta rodando em um dispositivo real ou emulador e ou browser, se possível teste em um dispositivo real, caso mesmo assim não apareça tente:

- Libere as configurações de desenvolvedor no celular e desmarque a opção "não manter processos em segundo plano",
- Caso esteja rodando com as opções `-l -c (ionic run android -l -c, para obter logs)` tente sem as opções adicionais, tive problema com algumas funções quando esta com log ativo.

Comment: Realmente faltam informações nesta pergunta. Não entendi porque a resposta foi negativada.